# If the Cramer Rao's Lower Bound tends to zero, is the estimator efficient?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian, parameter-estimation

I apply a nonlinear transformation to a linear estimator $\hat{\alpha}=f(\hat{\theta})$. Then
I find Cramer Rao's Lower Bound, and it asymptothically goes to zero. Does it means that my new estimator $\hat{\alpha}$ is efficient? Why?

I guess I should find $E(\hat{\alpha})$ and then see that $E(\hat{\alpha}) \rightarrow E(\hat{\theta})$, but I think it is not the point of the excercise, because it is a quite complicated nonlinearity.

Answer (score 1):

It is natural that the Cramer-Rao lower bound goes to zero as the number of samples increases and does not mean that the estimator is efficient.

According to Cramer-Rao lower bound  we may write:
$$ \text{Var}(\hat{\alpha})\geq \frac{\left(1+\frac{db}{d\alpha}\right)^2}{nI(\theta)}$$
where $b$ is the bias of estimator. It can be easily seen that the lower bound may go to zero due to the factor $n$ in the denumerator.

In order to show that an estimator is [efficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient_estimator), you should show that it is unbiased and also *attains* the lower bound in the Cramér–Rao inequality, for all $\theta$. This means that you should show that:

$$ \text{Var}(\hat{\alpha})= \frac{1}{nI(\theta)}$$

The concept of asymptotic efficiency is much more complicated. You may refer to p.21 of [this article](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jiantao/ibragimov.pdf) for more information.

*Cramér, Harald*, Mathematical methods of statistics, Princeton Mathematical series. 9. Princeton N. J.: Princeton University Press xvi, 575 p. (1946). [ZBL0063.01014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0063.01014).